# BackboneJS view keeps returning not defined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, coffeescript, haml

I can't seem to initialize my view. I tried looking around to see if this was asked before, but none of the solutions were working for me. My backbonejs view is below:

```
class FRView extends Backbone.View
  el: $ 'fr_view'

  initialize: ->
    console.log("created")

  render: ->
    console.log("here")
```

I'm attemtpting to intialize it inside of a partial using the code below:

```
:javascript
  var curr_view = new FRView()
```

but I keep getting the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: FRView is not defined
```

I've also tried

```
:javascript
  var curr_view = new Backbone.View.FRView()
```

Which lead to the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Backbone.View.FRView is not a constructor
```

From chrome sources browser I can see that the FRView file is loaded. I've also tried wrapping it in document onload but that didn't help. Any idea what might be causing this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I see two bugs, one you know about and one that you'll find out about soon.

The first problem (the one you know about) is caused by [CoffeeScript's scoping system](http://coffeescript.org/#lexical-scope):

> **Lexical Scoping and Variable Safety**
>   [...]
>   Although suppressed within this documentation for clarity, all CoffeeScript output is wrapped in an anonymous function:  `(function(){ ... })();`

So your `FRView` ends up looking more or less like this in JavaScript:

```
(function() {
  var FRView = ...
})();
```

and that means that `FRView` is only visible inside your CoffeeScript file.

The easiest solution is to put the class in the global scope:

```
class @FRView extends Backbone.View
```

or equivalently:

```
class window.FRView extends Backbone.View
```

Another common solution is to define a global namespace for your app and then put your class in that namespace:

```
class YourNameSpace.FRView extends Backbone.View
```

and say `new YourNameSpace.FRView` when instantiating it.

---

The other problem is that your `el` looks a bit confused:

```
el: $ 'fr_view'
```

There are two problems here:

1. That will be looking for an `<fr_view>` element in your HTML and you probably don't have such a thing. I'd guess that you really have something like `<div id="fr_view">` or maybe `<div class="fr_view">`, in that case you'd want to say:

   ```
   el: '#fr_view' # If you're using an id attribute.
   el: '.fr_view' # If you're using a CSS class.
   ```
2. `$ 'fr_view'` will be executed when the JavaScript is loaded and the element might not exist at that time. The solution to this problem is to use just the select for [`el`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-el) as above. There's no need to use a jQuery object for `el`, Backbone will do that for you when the view is instantiated.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I've fixed the el typo. For the FRView issue, I didn't want to add that view into the global namespace, so I tried using what you suggested:
    
    class FR.FRView extends Backbone.View

Then instantiating with:

    new FR.FRView()

but I still had the same undefined issue.  I also tried changing it to the global name space out, just to try and got the following error:

    Uncaught TypeError: this._ensureElement is not a function

where I defined FRVIew as:

    class @FRView extends Backbone.View

and instantiated it by using:

    new FRView()

Comment: Got it to work with the global namespace, turns out I accidentally deleted the 'new', adding that in again the global namespace works, but I would still like to use our own namespace for the stuff i'm adding in. Any idea what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Fixed it! After googling around about namespaces, I changed the view declaration to "class Portal.Views.FRView extends Backbone.View" and instantiated it using: "new Portal.Views.FRView;"

Answer (score 0):

As 'mu is too short' pointed out, the issue rooted from namespace/declaration issues. After googling around about namespace I skimmed through [this](http://codebeerstartups.com/2012/12/11-namespacing-in-backbone-js-learning-backbonejs/) and fixed the issue by changing my backbonejs view to:

```
class Portal.Views.FRView extends Backbone.View
    el: $ '#FRView'

    initialize: ->
        console.log("created")

    render: ->
        console.log("here")
```

and instantiated it using:

```
:javascript
    var frview = new Portal.Views.FRView();
```